# Titanium:Build Failed Error in IOS but No such issues in android?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I tried clean, build, rebuild and restart the studio. I also opened the componentsgallery.pch file where the version of the mentioned code were same.

Here is the error:

```
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   ProcessPCH /Users/macmini1/Documents/ReUsableComp/Appcelerator%20component/componentsgallery/build/iphone/build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/113008055249754235/componentsgallery_Prefix.pch.gch /Users/macmini1/Documents/ReUsableComp/Appcelerator%20component/componentsgallery/build/iphone/componentsgallery_Prefix.pch normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[ERROR] :   ProcessPCH /Users/macmini1/Documents/ReUsableComp/Appcelerator%20component/componentsgallery/build/iphone/build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/6376427032639609763/componentsgallery_Prefix.pch.gch /Users/macmini1/Documents/ReUsableComp/Appcelerator%20component/componentsgallery/build/iphone/componentsgallery_Prefix.pch normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[ERROR] :  (2 failures)
```

I want to know the reason and solution for this issue.

Comment: Please add more information: which Titanum SDK are you using, which Xcode version, Node version, java version, using hyperloop?, which modules are you using?

Comment: xcode version - 10.1, using hyperloop - yes, which modules - no modules used , java version - 1.0, Titanium SDK -7.5.0 , Node version - 5.5.1

Comment: please check your versions with `appc info`.  node should be 8.x or 10.x, Java should be 1.8. And compile your app with `--log-level trace` and add the error in the first post